# GNU make's install target to push files on a remote SSH?

Tags: linux, deployment, ssh, embedded-linux, gnu-make

I'm working on a project that needs to be tested on an embedded Linux system. After every little change, I have to scp all files to the device over a SSH connection. Can you suggest a more convenient way to deploy files on a remote target? For example some trick on make's install command:

```
make install INSTALL='scp 192.168.1.100:/'
```

or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use scp, you can probably also use rsync, specifically rsync over ssh. Use of rsync has as advantage is that it builds a delta of source and destination files, and transfers only what is necessary. In case of transfer after changing very little this would be of considerable benefit. I'd probably invoke it if building completes without error, like   make ... && upload     (where upload could be a script covering the details of transfer)

Comment: And what to do with `make`? Specially when makefile is created with autotools?

Comment: It's not only about pushing files to the target system. `make` also takes care of permissions, required directories that do not exist, and etc. I want `make` to perform file transfers and *all other stuff* that it do, on the target system.

Comment: rsync can replicate local permissions to remote files, and create directories, mirroring a local subtree, control group and ownership, etc

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, *sshfs* is often quite useful. You can mount a remote folder visible over *ssh* on to a folder on your local hard disk. Performance is not great, but certainly serviceable enough for a deploy step, and it's transparent to all tools.

Comment: I really hate sshfs. mount a remote device to your machine, then if for some reason your connection got broken, you will have to restart your machine. Because sshfs is too stupid that it can't even handle I/O freezes, such that you can't even read your local files.